# Messages with ERROR level in 'Test Execution Errors' section in Robot Framework log

Tags: robotframework

I'm using Robot Framework for test automation purposes.
In it's [User Guide](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.7.3#errors-and-warnings-during-execution) i can see lines with ERROR level in 'Test Execution Errors' section.
Documentation says, that I can add here messages by logging with WARN level.
But there is no information, how such messages with ERROR level can be put is this section from my own test scripts. Is there any way to add messages like this?

20090322 19:58:42.528   **ERROR**   Error Message

Comment: Do you also want the test to fail when such error message is displayed?

Comment: It appears that there is no way for a test to generate an error message in this section of the report. Have you considered filing a bug report or enhancement request?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the built in 'Log' keyword with appropriate warning levels. Should give you a similar output.

http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html?r=2.8.3#Log

Hope that helps.

Comment: No, it didn't help. When I use 'Log' with levels 'ERROR' and 'FAIL', message appears only inside keyword information and not in 'Test Execution Errors' section. 'WARN' level does it, but I need the same with 'ERROR'.